# Select every 1 hr timestamp record/based on condtion in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

Here, I need to fetch the records if Food Value is not 'Nan' and next 1 hr of timestamp row.

Comment: What does it mean "next 1 hr of timestamp row"?

Comment: I mean, Food value is showing Butter in the first row, i.e at 25-12-2021 10:19 time, So I need to fetch 25-12-2021 10:19 and 25-12-2021 11:19 record as well(1hr duration) but I don't need in between records

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the `Nan`s (and sort by Time, if it isn't sorted):

```
data_filtered = data[data['Food'].notna()].sort_values('Time', ascending = True)
```

And then use `groupby`:

```
data_filtered.groupby(data_filtered['Time'].dt.to_period('H')).first()
```

PS. please paste the example data instead of screen shot next time (it's easier to test it).

Comment: Daniel, Thanks for your help!! But, I need to fetch NAN value as well like ID 1234 in the above input